# R manipulate dataframe

Tags: r

In the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,
             Col1 = c("a","b","c"),
             Col2 = c("d", NA, "e"),
             Col3 = c("f", NA, NA))
> df
  ID Col1 Col2 Col3
1  1    a    d    f
2  2    b <NA> <NA>
3  3    c    e <NA>
```

each row represents a sequence with different length. Column 1 represents the first position in each sequence, column 2 the second position and so on.
The goal is to generate a new column that contains the last value other than NA of each sequence. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
df$NewCol <- c("f","b","e")
> df
  ID Col1 Col2 Col3 NewCol
1  1    a    d    f      f
2  2    b <NA> <NA>      b
3  3    c    e <NA>      e
```

Any ideas how to pick the last position in each row and assign it to the new column?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), rowSums(!is.na(df)))]
## [1] "f" "b" "e"
```

This is basically sums up the Non - `NA` sequences and indexes these columns per row

Or if you prefer doing it within a loop, could do

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) x[sum(!is.na(x))])
## [1] "f" "b" "e"
```

Another nice vectorized option (proposed by @akrun) is using `max.col`

```
df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df), 'last'))]
## [1] "f" "b" "e"
```